# Android 10 request permission for ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-10.0

I'm trying to comply with the Google requirements to request the permission ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION, for Android 10, but I don't seem to understand why there's no permission popup showing , like with the other permissions (ie, Location, storage,...)

The code I have is:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("TAG", "PERMISSION 'ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION' NOT GRANTED");

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION);
    } else
    {
        Log.d("TAG", "PERMISSION 'ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION' GRANTED");
    }
```

And I'm always ending up on the 'NOT GRANTED' flow, but the ActivityCompat.requestPermissions is not showing no popup!
Is there anything else I'm Missing ?

The manifest contains the 
    
and the app.gradle
 minSdkVersion 29
 targetSdkVersion 30

Running out of ideas, any help would be welcome.
Just to add, I'm running this on my Pixel 2, with the latest firmware available 10.0.0 (QP1A.191105.004, Nov 2019)

Comment: Are you requesting it in the manifest fil

Comment: Yes , the permission is requested on the manifest as well .

Comment: Did you ever work this out? Mine gets the popup on Android 10, but nothing on Android versions below that, and even with both permissions in the Manifest, I cannot get <10 working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check : [Privacy changes in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes)

From API 29(Android Q, Android 10)
Android App need permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

Before API 29 AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

check : [Google Fit APIs](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization)

And

If the system-auto grants the android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission, your app retains the permission after you update your app to target Android 10. However, the user can revoke this permission at any time in system settings.

Thanks.