# Android ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION on targetAPI = 29 and device's Android ver. < 10

Tags: android, permissions, google-fit, android-10.0, activity-recognition

My question is similar to [Android 10 request permission for ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958628/android-10-request-permission-for-activity-recognition) in a way that I also do not have a permission dialog showing on a device, but conditions are different.

My app is targeting API 29.

In manifest I have

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"/>` <- for test purposes

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>`

Requesting permission `Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` as usual:

```
fragment.requestPermissions(permissions, GOOGLE_FIT_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
```

On a device with Android 9 (API28) I do not receive a permission dialog for ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION and when I check a permission status, it is always denied.

I know that permission logic is working, as when I've added BODY_SENSORS permission, I do get a permission dialog for BODY_SENSORS, but not for ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION. As a result, a permission for BODY_SENSORS is granted, but for ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION - not:

permissions array:

`android.permission.BODY_SENSORS;android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION`

grantResults array:

`0;-1`

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. Please don't treat it as a source of truth, it is based on my own tests. Maybe someone from GoogleFit team can comment on this.

**Preconditions**: your app is targeting API29 or above.

Regardless of Android version, installed on a device, you should add permissions to Manifest file according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization#data_types_that_need_android_permissions). Side note: I was able to query GoogleFit HistoryApi even without those permissions on device with Android 9, but Android 10 will not work.

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

**For devices with Android 10 or above**: all is simple, you should [request runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), same which you've added to Manifest.

**For devices with Android version 9 or below**: you don't have to request runtime permissions. *This is the part which was not clear from the documentation.*
You may, of course, request those permissions, but for `android.permission. ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` you will not receive a permission dialog and as a result permission will not be granted.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, the only issue being on phones below 10, i get an error when I try to actually register the transistion, security exception, permission denied?

Comment: I'm not sure about issue you're having. But apart of Android permissions, you need also to ask for OAuth permissions. Hope you're doing so?